# Tkinter - Top and Left borders rectangle diminished by 1 pixel

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a maze generator in Python using Tkinter, and I have graphic problem concerning how Tkinter handles rectangles on top and left borders.

It seems to reduce their size by 1 pixel on these borders.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nj7C.png) where the width of the rectangles is fixed to 3px, but the top and left ones are 2px wide.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Here's the code creating these rectangles in case it's of use :

```
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,wall_width,self.h,fill='black') #Top
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,self.w,wall_width,fill='black') #Left
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,self.h - wall_width,self.w,self.h,fill='black') #Bottom
self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.w - wall_width,0,self.w,self.h,fill='black') #Right
```

wall_width is the width of a wall in pixels

self.h and self.w are the dimensions of the canvas

Comment: When you define your canvas, try setting `highlightthickness = 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution! How do I mark the question as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing highlightthickness from `Canvas` will allow top, left coordinates to start at 0,0 instead of 2,2

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, highlightthickness = 0, ...)
```